# intellij 14.0.3 Debugger will not stop on a breakpoints

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

I had IntelliJ 12 and it worked fine in debugging. Recently, i installed IntelliJ 14.0.3, but it will not stop on a breakpoints. What can i do to force this IDE to debug my code?

Comment: Maybe the breakpoints could be muted somehow? Check CTRL+SHIFT+A (Command+SHIFT+A) > Mute/unmute breakpoints

Comment: Did you do a full rebuild? Sounds like your code could be out of sync.

Comment: @ Bohuslav Burghardt.i checked it .it' not muted

Comment: @  vikingsteve i rebuild it many times .but it doesn't work

Comment: Are you not able to debug any break point or just some are skipped?

Comment: @ hitz I'm not enable to debug any breakpoint